# How to generate 10000 random numbers of timestamp type in one month?

Tags: dolphindb

If I use this way   times = 2019.01.01T08:00:00.000..2019.01.31T08:00:00.000 ;randTimes = rand(times,10000); times will occupy  30*24*3600*1000*8 = 20GB, so is there other way to do this work ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to find 10000 random integers between 0 and 30 * 86400000l (exclusive). See the code below.

```
range = 30 * 86400000l
times = 2019.01.01T08:00:00.000 + rand(range, 10000)
```